# How to add a node/vertex in a QGIS edit session?

Tags: qgis, editing, vertices

I'm doing some polygon (boundary) cleanup, and am wondering if it is possible to add a node/vertex to a set of selected polygons or even a single polygon.

By the way, the QGIS topology editing tools are incredible - extremely simple but very accurate and take so much of the work away from doing such manual work.

QGIS gives the ability to remove selected nodes - amazing that the topology is preserved and even improved when cleaning up excess nodes. Great stuff!

Comment: zoom to that line you will see a cross click on that and vertex wil be added

Comment: Yes did it and gave me right. In fact am using qgis 2.18.27 version. Thanks for upgrading me

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With the Node tool (called the Vertex Editor in QGIS 3.0+) selected, simply double-click on a line segment you want to add a node to
[image]

Comment: is there a way to add multiple vertices without having to double-click every time?

Comment: @NicoH Not as an edit session, but algorithmically, with tools like densify  https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/densifygeometries.html

Comment: Note QGIS3's Vertex Editor (called the node tool in QGIS2) has notable differences in its function compared to qgis 2 - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278217/how-does-the-qgis3-vertex-editor-work

Answer (score 2):

If you're having trouble getting the little cross to pop up on the segment you want to add the node to, check your snapping tolerances. Mine were too high, making it impossible to get it on shorter segments. Go to settings > options > digitizing > snapping > "search radius for vertex edits" and set it to something like 10 pixels. Mine was set to 100 map units because I am silly.

Answer (score 1):

To add to that, to delete a vertex, you will just need to select the point and hit the delete key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if in your Settings->Options, if the Snapping is set too large than the snapping feature will override you ability to find the cross for the add-vertex.  I went in and made mine small so that it would only snap when really close to a vertex.